# How do I retrieve data from this dynamic page using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been learning webscraping and I managed to scrape some data from a few sites like Booking, Tripadvisor, etc, but now I'm hardstuck trying to retrieve data from this [website](https://azul.krooze.com.br/search?destinations=4&sortBy=Recommended_WithTax&priceByCabin=false&taxAndFeesIncluded=true). I suspect this whole site is running something that makes it dynamic because a few of its containers change names at every refresh. The most I could do in this site was returning a few tags that are under "search-page kz-azu kz-b2c". The only thing that doesn't seem to change in the dynamic names is a small part of the name "c162". Everything inside a container called "app-search-page" my code doesn't see it. I've been using this to find classes and tags:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = 'https://azul.krooze.com.br/search?destinations=4&page=2&sortBy=Recommended_WithTax&priceByCabin=false&taxAndFeesIncluded=true'

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(15)

info_cruiser = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div")
elements = info_cruiser.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "*")

for element in elements:
    element_class = element.get_attribute('class')
    print(element.tag_name + " " + element_class + " " + element.text)
```

I tried first getting the tags to find their children afterwards, but some of them the code just can't seem to find. I just wanted to get all the text within this page.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to get? Right now you are trying to pull nearly 700 DIVs off that page and print their class attributes. What's the point? Your question is not clear.

Comment: At first I literally wanted every single text that shows up under "search-page kz-azu kz-b2c", but I realized that is very counter productive for learning anything, so I'm trying to retrieve ship names that are inside divs called departure-options. The objective is really learning simple stuff like getting text in dynamic sites and later on interacting with buttons and stuff.